# How can I make Sendgrid send the confirmation email?

Tags: express, jwt, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid to send email confirmation for newly created user accounts and despite using the right configuration, when I create a new user account I still don't get the confirmation email at the email address I used to create the account with.

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt  = require('jsonwebtoken');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    User.findOne({ email }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Email is taken',
                });
            }
        });

    const token = jwt.sign({ name, email, password }, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION, { expiresIn: '10m' });

    const emailData = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        to: email,
        subject: 'Account activation link',
        html: `
            <p>Use the following link to activate your chat</p>
            <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth/activate</p>
            <hr />
            <p>This email may contain sensitive information</p>
            <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>
        `
    };

    sgMail.send(emailData)
          .then(() => {
              res.json({ message: `Email was sent to ${email}. Activate your account` });
          })
};
```

The thing is I'm getting a 200 response from the server, so everything should work, but I don't get the confirmation email so that I can confirm and create the user and store it in MongoDB.

```
POST /api/signup 200 797.013 ms - 80
```

I want to make SendGrid to actually send the confirmation email to the email address I used to signup with.